# Excluding record NON unique Field Data

Tags: mysql

This is very similar to a a previous post I made recently:  But it is a bit different.  So if it looks familiar:  Please excuse my learning curve trying to understand :  "well what about this case  and what about that case....."

I have a nice little query that works.  It queries a single "Clients" table

Here is the table:    SQLFiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fcea

```
CREATE  TABLE `clients` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `state` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `foo` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `phone` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) );

INSERT INTO`clients` 
   (`name`, `address`, `state`, `foo`, `phone`) 
 VALUES 
   ('Jim', '123 Main', 'MO', '876', '2038221661');
INSERT INTO`clients` 
   (`name`, `address`, `state`, `foo`, `phone`) 
 VALUES 
   ('Tom ', '234 Elm', 'MO', '433', '2038221661');
INSERT INTO`clients` 
   (`name`, `address`, `state`, `foo`, `phone`) 
 VALUES 
   ('Steve', '653 Pine', 'CT', '863', '5125901977');
INSERT INTO`clients` 
   (`name`, `address`, `state`, `foo`, `phone`) 
 VALUES 
   ('Dave', '654 Oak', 'NV', '872', '8769085435');
INSERT INTO`clients` 
   (`name`, `address`, `state`, `foo`, `phone`) 
 VALUES 
   ('Oscar', '622 FIrst ', 'LA', '625', '5125551212');
```

Here is the query

```
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       address, 
       phone 
FROM   clients 
WHERE  state IN ( 'MO', 'LA', 'CT' ) 
       AND foo > 40 
ORDER  BY foo
```

It Returns:

```
2   Tom     234 Elm     2038221661
5   Oscar   622 First   5125551212
3   Steve   653 Pine    5125901977
1   Jim     123 Main    2038221661
```

I want to TOTALLY SUPPRESS any records that don't have totally unique phone numbers.

I need it suppress (1) Jim  and (2) Tom and Return

```
5   Oscar   622 First   5125551212
3   Steve   653 Pine    5125901977
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       address, 
       phone 
FROM   clients 
WHERE  state IN ( 'MO', 'LA', 'CT' ) 
       AND foo > 40 
       AND phone not in 
       (
          select phone 
          from clients 
          group by phone
          having count(*) > 1
       )
ORDER  BY foo
```

Comment: We both posted at the same time :)

Comment: Well Thanks guys.  I does work.    Now I ned to learn to optimize. On 200,000 records the query is taking ~39 seconds!

Comment: Run `explain select ...` and you can see where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this with a `group by`:

```
SELECT id, name, address, phone 
FROM   clients 
WHERE  state IN ( 'MO', 'LA', 'CT' ) AND foo > 40 
group by phone
having count(*) = 1
ORDER  BY foo;
```

This groups by the phone number.  The `id`, `name`, and `address` come from arbitrary records.  But, because there is only one (due to the `having` clause), these would be the fields from that one record.

Answer (score 1):

This should exclude duplicate numbers:

```
SELECT id, 
   name, 
   address, 
   phone 
FROM   clients 
WHERE  state IN ( 'MO', 'LA', 'CT' ) 
   AND foo > 40 
   AND phone not in (select phone from clients 
                    group by phone having count(*) > 1)
ORDER  BY foo
```